# android: get the service reference or object by RunningServiceInfo or hashcode

Tags: android

I would like to get a service reference (or object) from another app. I know that I can get RunningServiceInfo from the android system, and I can get the hashcode from RunningServiceInfo. For example

```
    Context c = null;
    try {
        c = createPackageContext(wanted_app_name, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (service_class_name.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            do_what_I_want(service_context);
        }
    }
```

However, I need the **service_context** in function **do_what_I_want()**. I don't know how to get the object of reference of the service. I know I can get the hashcode of the service by **service.hashCode()**, but I don't know if it will help to find the reference or context or object of this service. Any one can help with this?